# Removing XML tags but not data

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML string in Java that looks like this

```
<priceFactor>
    <client>string</client>
   ...
    <priceFactorID>
        <exchangeCode>fgdf</exchangeCode>
        <productCode>dfg</productCode>
        <secType>dgf</secType>
    </priceFactorID>

</priceFactor>
```

I want to remove the priceFactorID *tags* but not the child elements. So, I want something that looks like this:

```
<priceFactor>
    <client>string</client>
   ...

        <exchangeCode>fgdf</exchangeCode>
        <productCode>dfg</productCode>
        <secType>dgf</secType>

</priceFactor>
```

I can try string manipulation, but I was wondering if there's a more efficient way in Java to manipulate XML

Comment: Perhaps [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) is appropriate?

Comment: You cannot simply remove a node, visually or in ui, you can do it. Actually, you have to parse, form the elements and write once again so that you can see the new structure. Others can comment on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    NodeList neighbors = priceFactorNode.getChildNodes();
    Node unwantedNode = neighbors.item(1);
    NodeList children = unwantedNode.getChildNodes();
    priceFactorNode.removeChild(unwantedNode);
    for(int x = 0; x < children.getLength(); x++) {
        priceFactorNode.appendChild(children.item(x));
    }
```

where priceFactorNode is implied to be the Node of tag PriceFactor. This should remove the node that you do not want after grabbing its children, and then append the children to the deleted node's parent node, essentially "deleting" the node. You might want to change the code around to get your desired results.